# Magento 2 developer mode failing to generate content

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

It seems my developer mode in magento 2 stopped working. The only thing that seems to be deployed properly by it is the _requiresjs directory. Nothing is however done for frontend, any ideas what might cause this?

It renders the page just fine except for lack of css, js and other things that should recide in pub/static/frontend. Running deploy static command do however work.

I am suspecting language settings but not sure if that is a red herring or not. Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 symlinks or generates pub/static content using pub/static.php. This relies on the web server rule being correct to first try reading the file from pub/static/...file or to fallback and route the request through static.php if it's not found.

in nginx this is the rule that make is work:

```
location /static/ {
...
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
```

for apache it's the .htaccess file in pub/static which will require you have mod rewrite enabled.

I would check:

- webserver configuration
- pub/static.php hasn't been accidentally deleted
- pub/static has read/write/execute permission for the webserver and php user (typically www-data)

Comment: I have checked all these things and they all seem correct. Still no luck, might try and change to using nginx. Running on apache2 right now through mamp.

Answer (score 0):

I had to redeploy static content using php/bin command after switching to developer mode.  If on your local and using Grunt, you can also rerun the commands such as clean and exec then have it recompile.